# How do i add two dates that are saved in .json files?

Tags: python, json, date, calendar, sum

I am having a hard time summing two dates that are saved in two separate json files. I want to add set dates together which are saved in separate libraries.

The first file (A1.json) contains: {"expires": "2019-09-11"}

The second file (Whitelist.json) contains: {"expires": "0000-01-00"}

These dates are created by using tkcalendar and are later exported to these seperate files, the idea being that summing them lets me set a time date one month into the future. However, I can't seem to add them together without some form of an error.

I have tried converting the json files to strings in python and then adding them and also using the striptime command to sum the dates.

Here is the relevant chunk of the code:

```
{with open('A1.json') as f:
data=json.loads(f.read())
for material in data.items():
A1 = (format(material[1]['expires']))
with open('Whitelist.json') as f:
data=json.loads(f.read())
for material in data.items():
A2 = (format(material[1]['expires']))

print(A1+A2)}
```

When this is used, they just get pasted one after another. They don't get summed the way I need.

I also have tried the following code:

```
{t1 = dt.datetime.strptime('A1', '%d-%m-%Y')
t2 = dt.datetime.strptime('Whitelist', '%d-%m-%Y')
time_zero = dt.datetime.strptime('00:00:00', '%d/%m/%Y')
print((t1 - time_zero + Whitelist).time())}
```

However, this constantly gives out `ValueError: time data does not match format '%y:%m:%d'.`

What I expect is the sum of 2019-09-11 and 0000-01-00's result is 2019-10-11. However, the result is 2019-09-110000-01-00. Trying the strptime method gives out ValueErrors such as: `ValueError: time data does not match format '%y:%m:%d'.`

Thank you in advance, and I apologize if I did something wrong on my first post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use `pandas`:

- the actual format of the `json` file isn't provided, so use something like the following to get the data into a `DataFrame`:

  - `pd.read_json('A1.json', orient='records')`: parameters will depend on the format of the file
  - `json_normalize`
- `d2` is not a proper `datetime` format so don't try to convert it.
- the `Code` section below, will use a `dict` to set up the `DataFrame` for the example.

### `json` files to `DataFrames`:

```
df1 = pd.read_json('A1.json', orient='records')
df2 = pd.read_json('Whitelist.json', orient='records')
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['expires'] = df1.expires
df['d2'] = df2.expires
```

### Code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"expires": ["2019-09-11", "2019-10-11", "2019-11-11"],
                    "d2": ["0000-01-00", "0000-02-00", "0000-03-00"]})
```

[image]

#### Expand `d2` using `str.split`:

```
df.expires = pd.to_datetime(df.expires)
df[['y', 'm', 'd']] = df.d2.str.split('-', expand=True)
```

[image]

#### Use [`pd.DateOffset`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.DateOffset.html):

```
df['expires_new'] = df[['expires', 'm']].apply(lambda x: x[0] + pd.DateOffset(months=int(x[1])), axis=1)
```

[image]

- if `d2` is expected to have more than just a new `m` or month value, the `lambda` expression can be changed to call a function that adjusts for `y`, `m`, and `d` values.